# MPMoviePlayer play on when application goes Background when incoming call is coming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an audio streamer and have declared an interruption listener,
   that means when an interruption occurs - like an incoming call or an sms.After complete    my call again automatically play that audio live stream

### Explain

my first question Is it possible.... (that means if my song is ten min . After 2 min playing, suddenly incoming call is coming at that time i am talking 4 min... So my song should be continue from 6th min(that means 4 min should be background running without noise ) )
 I am **MPMoviePlayer** in **IOS5**

```
player =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:audioUrl];
[player prepareToPlay];
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you can do it by:

1. Capture the current time when you app got interrupted.
2. When applicationDidBecomeActive got called. Calculate the elapsed time base on the time captured above.
3. Initialize the MPMoviePlayerController with initialPlaybackTime to seek to the calculated offset.

Comment: how to recognize ,when my  app got interrupted ?

Comment: applicationWillResignActive: and applicationDidBecomeActive: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html